# Will Microsoft Teams - Multi-Window Chat Featured ID: 57292 which allows a user to "close a chat window" provide any API events to Bot Developers?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Currently, Teams has no way to close a chat window in the traditional manner (for example as in SfB clients)

Now Teams appears to be  gaining this feature as part of Multi-Window Chat Featured ID: 57292 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=57292

This allows a user to at least undock a chat, and even get appearance of the chat as a separate application window in the windows task bar.  As a consequence, the traditional X to close chat window option now is available (at least it undocks the popout chat window back to Team client)

Question: How can a bot developer or remote parties get any indication that the user has closed (X'ed the chat) window?  This could be by means of an event in the bot framework or a call back from Graph for example.

This is needed for certain contact center applications where it is important to know that the user has "left" the chat.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be a feature request on the specific product, not a question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported. Can you please make your features suggestions on the [Microsoft Teams feedback portal on UserVoice](https://aka.ms/microsoftteamsplatformsuggestions)

Comment: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40367467-callback-event-needed-in-graph-or-bot-framework-fo